# Angular routing with passing id not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an app with Ionic. I am pretty much new to Angular and I am trying to make a route with passing id. In my article page I have a button link for creating comment page. This is the link on my article page:

```
<button class="button button-light block comment">
          <a href="#/main/article/{{article.id}}/comment" name="comments-section"></a>
          Write a comment
        </button>
```

And this is my route:

```
.state('main.comment', {
    url: '/article/{id}/comment',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/comment.html',
        controller: 'CommentController'
      }
    },
    authenticate: true
  })
```

So, when I check the link with inspect element, the link looks fine, I get the article id, but nothing happens, no errors in the console so I can't tell what is happening.
And the link for the article that I have on the front page where I have an article list has a same structure and it works:

```
<a href="#/main/article/{{article.id}}" nav-direction="forward" class="article-image-link">
```

**Update**

The mistake was that the markup was wrong for the link. A tag can't be below a button, should be either inside a button or on it's own.

Comment: I think it should be /article/:id/comment

Comment: But I already have a link like that on the article list page for the article, that works  and looks like this: <a href="#/main/article/{{article.id}}" nav-direction="forward" class="article-image-link">

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that the `id` in your state's url is wrapped inside swirly brackets. It must be defined as: `/article/:id/comment`.

Anyways, I would definitely recommend you start using `ui-sref` as it's a directive offered by `ui-router` and it's meant to solve this exact problem.

**ui-sref**

> A directive that binds a link (`<a>` tag) to a state. If the state has an associated URL, the directive will automatically generate & update the `href` attribute via the [$state.href()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#wiki-statehrefstateorname--params--options) method. Clicking the link will trigger a state transition with optional parameters. Also middle-clicking, right-clicking, and ctrl-clicking on the link will be handled natively by the browser. [Source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)

Your anchor would look something like this:

```
<a ui-sref="main.comment({ id: article.id })" name="comments-section"></a>
```

Comment: How do I add that id will be passed with that route to a state provider or do I leave it like it is now?

Comment: Make sure to change your state url to `/article/:id/comment`

Answer (score 0):

You could try two changes to you code.

1. Mentioning route params like `url: '/article/:id/comment',` when you describe a state.
2. When you have a view in a nested state try using `content@main.comment`as the name of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `ui-sref`:

```
<button class="button button-light block comment">
    <a ui-sref="main.comment({id: article.id})" name="comments-section"></a>
          Write a comment
</button>
```

Beside it's hard to say what you're trying to achieve with this state, because it could look like this:

```
.state('main.comment', {
    url: '/article/{id}/comment',
    views: {
      'content@main': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/comment.html',
        controller: 'CommentController'
      }
    },
    authenticate: true
  })
```

or

```
.state('main.comment', {
    url: '/article/{id}/comment',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/comment.html',
        controller: 'CommentController'
      }
    },
    authenticate: true
  })
```